# How can I get the HTML form results in the same page of browser?

Tags: php, html

I am typing a simple codes in PHP and HTML. How can I display the result in same page of browser not in another window tab or page?

Following is the simple HTML formula code:

To add two numbers and display on the same page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sum of two numbers </title>
<body>

    <form action="sum.php" method="POST">
    First Number:  <input type="Text" Name="Num1"><br>
    Second Number: <input type="Text" Name="Num2"><p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and `sum.php` file is as follows.

```
<?php
// add First and Second Numbers
$sum = $_POST["Num1"] + $_POST["Num2"];
// their sum is diplayed as
echo "The sum of  First Number (".$_POST["Num1"].") and
Second Number  (".$_POST["Num2"].") is $sum";
?>
```

Comment: you could either submit the form to the same page the form is on or use javascript

Comment: Search for submit form with ajax ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sum of two numbers </title>
<body>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    First Number:  <input type="Text" Name="Num1"><br>
    Second Number: <input type="Text" Name="Num2"><p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>

<?php
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST["Num1"]) && isset($_POST["Num2"])){
    // add First and Second Numbers
    $sum = $_POST["Num1"] + $_POST["Num2"];
    // their sum is diplayed as
    echo "The sum of  First Number (".$_POST["Num1"].") and
    Second Number  (".$_POST["Num2"].") is $sum";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained **why** it worked.

Comment: As you see above i have two files separate in html and php. With form action i can connect sum.php but when i run my html form and enter data in it, the results is displayed in another page of browser. Now KeyboardSmasher has merged the html and php file and added some code like echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and this helped me to show the results displayed in same page. You can run the code to see its working.

Comment: I just want to say that I thought it was funny that we all didn't notice the missing "closing head tag" :P Good thing browsers don't care whether HTML is valid or not. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine the PHP code and the HTML code in the same file.
Then you just set the forms action to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sum of two numbers </title>
<body>
<?php 
if($_POST["Num1"]=='' And $_POST["Num2"]==''){
?>      
    <form action="sum.php" method="POST">
    First Number:  <input type="Text" Name="Num1"><br>
    Second Number: <input type="Text" Name="Num2"><p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
<?php }else{
// add First and Second Numbers
$sum = $_POST["Num1"] + $_POST["Num2"];
// their sum is diplayed as
echo "The sum of  First Number (".$_POST["Num1"].") and
Second Number  (".$_POST["Num2"].") is $sum";
} ?>
</body>
</html>

and sum.php file is as follows.
```

Comment: but is you mean "without reloading page where the form is", then there shuld be different code.